# Using java truststore from s3 bucket

Tags: java, ssl, amazon-s3, truststore, cacerts

We have a requirement to store custom Java trust store file in S3 bucket and have various applications refer that common trust store by using JVM argument-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore

Giving S3 bucket location is not working for us

**Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<s3 bucket location for Java trust store path>**

All the apps are containerized and we have set above JVM parameters in docker file.

Comment: Yeah, the JVM does not know S3 and has no idea what to do with that url. Instead you should download the file first, store it somewhere locally and then set the property pointing to the local file. Alternatively not sure if that works let the application itself download the trust store and set its own system property after it downloaded and stored the file somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Even I was doubting that JVM can't refer external S3 bucket location. Problem of not using the trust store file within the application code is we have a lot of apps so we want to decouple the application code for TLS cert management

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: We are using AWS environment. There are 2 apps: app1 and app2. app1 invokes app2 over https protocol. We created a custom java trust store, imported the ,certificate of app2 in the trust store, placed the trust store in s3 bucket. In app1 docker file, we added JVM arguments to refer S3 trust store file which is not working. Adding the dockerfile content below:

Comment: `FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine    
RUN apk --no-cahce add aws-cli  
ARG AWS_KEY  
ARG AWS_SECRET_KEY  
ARG AWS_REGION='us-east-1'  

RUN aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_KEY \  
&& aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_KEY \  
&& aws configure set default.region $AWS_REGION  

COPY app.jar /usr/app/  
WORKDIR /usr/app/  
RUN sh -c 'touch app1.jar'  
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<s3_path_to_custom_trusstore>","- 
 Djavax.net.ssl.trsutStorePassword=changeit","-jar","app1.jar"]`